# Is it a common to use "I like the idea" to express "I believe"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Suppose that there is a guy applying a job

> I also feel that your company will continue to evolve in the future, and **I like the idea**
>   of contributing to that development.

I thought the expression "I like the idea" was used to agree 
 the idea/solution/plan from someone else.

Is it a commonly used way to express his/her own idea/solution/plan?

Answer (score -1):

No. The phrase "I like the idea" is almost always intended to be taken literally, and is never a statement of belief. It can, in fact, be used to convey a *lack* of belief. The statement "I like the idea of the Christian god," absent any context, almost certainly indicates that while the speaker or writer likes the *idea* of the Christian god, they don't actually *believe* such a deity exists in reality.

In your example, the candidate believes the company will "continue to evolve." They go on to express their own preference for a future that includes the candidate contributing to that evolution, which can be read as a desire to work for the company. On reflection, using the phrase in this way is pretty passive language for a job application, but I probably wouldn't have noticed as a native speaker if I had been the hiring manager reading the application. The clause could have been replaced by

> ...and I want to contribute to that development.

or

> ...I think my talents could contribute to that development.

and hold the same meaning, while being more assertive, confident language.

To answer your final question, one could offer a solution by saying "I like the idea of..." and stating their proposed solution, but it's an oddly passive statement for an original idea. Not incorrect, just odd. It fits much better as a refrence to an earlier point.

> Person A (to a group): We need to raise money, any ideas?
>
> Person B: We could hold a bake sale.
>
> Person C: Let's do a carwash.
>
> *other suggestions are made and discussed*
>
> Person B: I still **like the idea** of holding a bake sale.

One could also express agreement with another's plan by saying "I like that idea."

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. Thank you. "They go on to express their preference" implies someone else said "like the idea", but actually not, the quote is said by only one guy, the candidate. That's why I asked "his/her own ..."

Comment: @WXJ96163 Ah! I will make one more edit to address this

Comment: You are so nice. Thank you so much! Btw, I guess "the phrase is meant literally" means "the phrase means literally", right?

Comment: @WXJ96163 Essentially, that's correct. Whereas "hold you horses" actually means "be patient," "I like the idea" literally means "I like the idea."